# PyQt5 QML application crashes when importing QtQuick.Controls 2

Tags: python, qt, qml, pyqt5

I'm starting to learn QtQuick & QML. While experimenting I encountered strange behavior when launching QML application from PyQt (PyQt5 on x64 Windows 10 machine).

If in my qml file I do `import QtQuick.Controls 1.4`, everything works correctly. However, when I do `import QtQuick.Controls 2.0` (or higher), application crashes... To make it more fun, I don't even need to use anything from Controls for app to crash. To add colors: launching both versions using *qmlscene.exe* works.

My QML file (the crashing one - it's enough to change 2.0 to 1.4 to make it work):

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.5

Window {
    id: wnd
    visible: true
    width:640
    height: 480
    title: "QML Test"
}
```

Python code:

```
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl

from PyQt5.QtCore import QT_VERSION_STR, PYQT_VERSION, PYQT_CONFIGURATION

import sys

def main():
    print("Qt version:", QT_VERSION_STR)
    print('PyQt verion:', PYQT_VERSION)

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    print('create engine')
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    print('loading...')
    engine.load(QUrl('qml_test.qml'))
    print('loaded')
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        return -1

    print('start')
    return app.exec()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When launching using `python .\qml_test.py` application crashes silently and here is my console output:

```
Qt version: 5.13.0
PyQt verion: 331008
create engine
loading...
```

I've already searched Google for any hint, unfortunately to no avail.
**Does anyone know if I encountered bug in PyQt or maybe I have something wrong with code/environment?**

Output from qmlscene with QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS: [log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-QORq8lOC3RffkSOzxN8ebFsZvt84sOE) 
Output from PyQt launch with QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS: [log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1En3TISKiXzYZo5KQVfMIkf97LzLdKvKK)

Comment: what are output of `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 python .\qml_test.py` and `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 qmlscene qml_test.qml`

Comment: @eyllanesc Attached to question.